# Как сделать условную компиляцию только для одной заданной БД?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть БД для разработки, в которой есть некоторые пакеты, которые в конечном итоге копируются на производственную БД.

Ищу способ, используя условную компиляцию в спецификации пакета, которая включит компиляцию заданных функций только для этой одной БД разработки, но они будут исключены из компиляции на всех остальных БД.

Нет прав добавить что-то в производственной БД - никаких новых глобальных переменных/настроек и т.п.

Есть ли возможность сделать что-то подобное:

```
$IF {{development_server}} $THEN
    my_proc;
$END
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [PL/SQL - conditional compilation specific to one database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50064436) от участника [@Major Major](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1171899/major-major)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/50064436

Answer (score 3):

Установите только на БД для разработки свой специфический [флаг компиляции](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-623713EB-4FD1-4C8B-955C-4135342F5F68):

```
PLSQL_CCFLAGS='flagName:<true|false>'
```

В продуктивной БД он будет не определён, что по умолчанию всегда - `FALSE`.

```
create or replace package pkg1 is
    init int := 0;
    procedure prodproc (par varchar2);
$if $$ccflag_devl $then
    procedure devlproc (par varchar2);
$end
end;
/
create or replace package body pkg1 is
    procedure prodproc (par varchar2) is
    begin
        dbms_output.put_line ('Production  '||par||' code executed.');
    end;
$if $$ccflag_devl $then
    procedure devlproc (par varchar2) is
    begin
        dbms_output.put_line ('Development '||par||' code executed.');
    end;
$end
begin
$if $$ccflag_devl $then
   prodproc ('init'); 
   devlproc ('init');
$else
   prodproc ('init'); 
$end
end;
/
exec pkg1.devlproc ('some')
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 12:
PLS-00302: component 'DEVLPROC' must be declared
```

Ошибка как и ожидалось, флаг еще не установлен. Установите его и скомпилируйте пакет:

```
alter session set plsql_ccflags='ccflag_devl:true';
alter package pkg1 compile; 

exec pkg1.devlproc

Production  init code executed.
Development init code executed.
Development some code executed.
```